# Using a pure C++ compiler versus Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ide, compiler-construction

I searched around for the answers to these questions, but I have had little luck.  So, I thought I would post them here to get some clarification.  If this is a duplicate, please let me know, and I will close this.

Okay, with that said, I would like to begin learning C++.  I come from a C# background and I have a great respect for Visual Studio and what it can do.  Now, my question is.  How well does Visual Studio's compiler work for C++ as opposed to a non-Microsoft version (such as MinGW)?

My thing is this.  I have nothing wrong with Microsoft, but I would really like to learn C++ in a "pure" form and not scewed by any particular implementation.  How reliant is Visual C++ on the .NET Framework?  Can a "pure" C++ application be created through Visual Studio without any .NET usage or overhead?  Does the Visual Studio compiler compile C++ into CIL like it does with C#/VB, or does it compile it all the way down as others do?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Note that MinGW, as a GCC-based compiler has a lot of non-standard options too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Visual C++ compiler will compile C++ code into standalone EXEs that have nothing to do with the .NET framework.

The only way to get the .NET baggage thrown in is to compile the C++ as "managed".

If you create a new project (File|New|New Project) Then choose "Win32" from the Visual C++ submenu in the project types and choose "Win32 Console Application" Visual studio will create a simple project with a couple of source files that will compile to a little executable.

Most of the time, Visual C++ is very similar to other compilers. Avoid #pragmas, microsoft libraries (MFC, ATL) and you should be fine.

Edit (thanks Cheeso) - [Documentation of where Visual C++ diverges from standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78.aspx).

In general I would advise using boost libraries for threads and networking because they work on many platforms (i.e linux). Also if your code can compile in GCC and Visual Studio then you are doing a good job keeping it portable.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.  This was what I was hoping for!  

Also, thanks to everyone else who replied!

Comment: MS documents the places where VC++ diverts from the C++ standard.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78.aspx

Comment: @Cheeso: These are only "officially recognized", known issues. In reality, there are more.

Comment: @andreyT - yeah, the only real solution is to compile using two compilers from early on.

Answer (score 6):

The most recent versions of VC++ have become significantly more compliant to the C++ standard, so it's not really an issue to write "pure" C++ using Visual Studio, presuming that you stay out of the Windows API, COM+ and ATL. In fact, the documentation with Visual Studio is very rich, with details on the standard libraries and the STL, so it can help you learn a great deal. It can't teach you everything, but it's certainly loaded up with a wealth of information that is portable to any compiler and it is very easily accessbible inside the IDE.

Comment: Also, the debugger is still one of the best around, especially since you can drag and drop the program counter (little yellow arrow during debugging) anywhere and the watch window does pretty sophisticated evaluation of the statements you type.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a new solution you should choose new Win32 Project, or Win32 Console Application, and check the 'Empty Project' option. Then you can add a main.cpp file, and add your standard C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

If you like Visual Studio, go ahead and use it to learn C++ -- I haven't used the very latest version, but even the previous one was pretty standards-compliant, C++-wise, and I assume the latest one can only have gotten better.  You can have many different kinds of project in Visual Studio, including "console apps", which are the "plain vanilla" kind you could make on any platform, and also many other kinds, such as, windows apps using the good old win32 api, ones made with MFC or other frameworks older than .NET, .NET ones using "managed code", etc.

Just make sure you always work in a "console app" project, and you'll be operating pretty closely to how you would be on other platforms and/or with other C++ IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

If you limit yourself to writing ANSI C++ compliant code then what you write in VS will work in other compilers, until you have to interact with a graphic interface or IO.  Then you need to make certain that you are using something that is portable, such as OpenGL, and not DirectX.

To set your project the steps here may be useful:
http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/447572-strict-ansi-c

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 comes with a very good, C++98 standard compliant pure C++ compiler. If you are interested in pure C++, don't forget to disable language extensions in project settings and you are good to go. Nobody is going to force you to use .NET framework, MFC or anyting like that. Just pure core C++ language and C++ standard library.

Of course, just like any other compiler, it has known non-compliance issues, but in general it is, again, surprisingly good. Older versions of their compiler (MS VS 6.0 specifically) suffered from many non-compliance problems and could not even compile its own header files with language extensions disabled. In 2005 version they fixed a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

After creating a standard Win32 project, you can turn up the compliance a bit more. On the project properties sheet, there's a C/C++ category, with a Language entry. This lists a number of cases where VC++ *can* differ from the standard. Here, you'd want to turn OFF language extensions, and turn ON "wchar_t as built-in type", "for-loop conformance" and "RTTI support".